# Save specific combination of layers as PNG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Unfortunately I don't have any experience yet with PS scripts, so I would highly appreciate your help. I'm looking for a way to export a specific combination of layers to a PNG.

---

My file is laid-out where I have 12 groups.

Group 1-11 is named after a colour. Each group from 1 to 11 contains 6 layers named as T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6.
Group 12 is different, it has 6 layers: R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6.

I would like to export the combination of the layers to PNG as follows (keeping the original canvas size, not trimmed to layer content sizes.)

R1+T1 (R1 from group 12 and all the T1-s from Group 1-11). In total that is 11 variations.

R2+T2 (once again, R2 is from Group 12 and T2-s are from Group 1-11.)

R3+T3
R4+T4
R5+T5 and
R6+T6.

I tried to do so with PS built in script, but it did not really work, it exported bad layers and just kept going and going.

Would you be so kind to help me how can I achieve my goal with all the different PNG files described above?

---

### Additional information:

The "R" layers blend mode are set to "Color dodge" I would like to keep this when merging and exporting with the T layers.

The linked topic did not solve my problem - Composite script gave me an error when opening in CS5.5. Also, I'm not sure if it answers the same question.

---

### Updates

Layer comps should be the solution. At least it saves time by clicking "Save as" and set output as PNG and also adding a name to each file.

So thanks for your help, it's far better than doing everything manually!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why can't you just turn the respective layers on and just export it manually?

Comment: I can, but it takes at least 1 hour to do so. Turning layers on and off, saving them, etc. And I have 10+ psd files with the same task.

Comment: Is this a catalog or something? Some images with your post would help. It also sounds like you need a better layer management system.

Comment: Nope, I am building an online visual builder, where visitors can change colour of each design element. So I have to export all parts (T1-T2-T3-...) in that 11 colour. Upload, and then visitors can mix each element and voila, their desired graphics is ready.

Comment: Yes, I checked that topic, but I could not load the script (Composition Composer) to my CS5.5.

Comment: Well you might be out of luck. A simple search shows numerous scripting options. You might need to upgrade to a CC version.

Comment: Additionally I'd have a look at ImageMagick. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29865961/3302793

Comment: Yep, also done research regarding this option. But as mentioned, my "R" layers have a belding mode set and I'm sure merging layers outside of PS will lose that blending. Now I'm trying to get familiar with Layer comps.
But I'm sure there must be a script somewhere. I don't have the money to upgrade.

Comment: Layer comps should be the solution. At least it saves time by clicking "Save as" and set output as PNG and also adding a name to each file. So thanks for your help, it's far better than doing everything manually!